# non-Lebesgue measure for the Doubling map

Tags: ergodic-theory

Does there exists invariant non Lebesgue probability measures for the doubling map $T:[0,1)\rightarrow [0,1]$ defined by

$
T(x)=2x \,\text{mod}(1)?
$

So a probability measure different from $\lambda([a,b))=b-a$, but still invariant under $T$.

Comment: Constant multiples of $\lambda$ give stupid examples.

Comment: @Kevin That won't work.  $\lambda([1/4,3/4]) = 1/2$, but the image under the doubling map is $[0,1]$, which has Lebesgue measure 1.

Comment: I suspect that will mean there are no such measures, or at least that they have to be fairly exotic.  Point measures, like I was originally thinking, will have problems.  The doubling means you'd need an infinite number of point masses of equal measure, which can't happen in a probability measure.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I don't understand your comments. You seem to do a confusion on the definition of an invariant measure. The Dirac mass at any fixed point of T is invariant. So the Dirac masses at 0 and at 1 are invariant, and so any convex combination of those two as well. There are also plenty of invariant measures which are continuous singular with respect to Lebesgue, and which can be constructed as Gibbs measures.

Comment: @Ahriman I think you may be right.  I think I was using $T$ for the invariance check, rather than $T^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3624027/lebesgue-continuous-borel-probability-measures-on-0-1-ergodic-with-respect?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

How about a Riesz Product measure? For example if $|a| < 1$ then the weak-* limit of
$$ \prod_{k=1}^n (1 + a\cos(2^k x) ) $$
is $2$-invariant and not equivalent to lebesgue.